# Removing file and all links - hard and symbolic

Tags: bash, debian

How can I remove file and all links related to file to remove?

`rm -f file.txt` removes just the file. Futher more, if there any other hard links of file system the file will not be removed.

What is the most usefull way to do this?

Or may be there is a command to get full list of links of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ls -li filename` to get the inode of the file. Then `find <the same filesystem> -inum <inode>` to get the files with the same inode

This will ensure you find all the copies of the file (hardlinks). The softlinks are not interest because they just point to the original file

Comment: ... they just point to the original file*name*. But I agree with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To find all links to a file, hard and symbolic, use the `find` command with the `-L` and `-samefile` options, like this:

```
find / -L -samefile file.txt
```

You could combine that with `rm` or with the `find` `-delete` action to delete those files in one command, but it would make me nervous to do that without reviewing the list of files to be deleted first. Also, if you remove file.txt before you've found all the links to it, it will be much more difficult to find the links.

Comment: The `-L` should precede the search path, but I don't recommend it, as symbolic links can take the search into other file systems. You are better to use `find <File System root> -lname "*FileName" -exec ls -l {} \;`. The `*` is because the link may be specified as a simple name or preceded by a directory path (absolute or relative), but it may give false finds - names with extra characters in front, or the same name in other directories: the `ls` will show you what the link contains, and the highlighting will show which are dead if you run the command after deleting the file and hard links.